# name 'd' is not defined

Tags: python

```
a = input('введите первое число')
b = input('введите второе число')
c = input('введите 1 это +; 2 это - 3; это *; или 4 это /')
if(c == 1):
    d =int(a) + int(b)
elif(c == 2):
    d =int(a) - int(b)
elif(c == 3):
    d =int(a) * int(b)
elif(c == 4):
    d =int(a) / int(b)
print(d)
```

В консоли ошибка:

```
name 'd' is not defined
```

Comment: а в третьей строке не выдавал ошибку? c = input('введите + - * или /') if c == '+'

Comment: Продолжу `if(c == +)` на самом деле `c` при любом вводе не будет равно `+`, Вы можете привести `c` к строке  и сравнить строку с символом `"+"`

Comment: @Иван, не нужно править код в вопросе на правильный, это ломает смысл ответов на данный вопрос. Верните изменения и сделайте ответ на свой вопрос с правильным кодом :)

Answer (score 4):

> тяп-ляп, вот и вышел корабь

это если коротко по вашему коду

```
c = int(input('введите + - * или /'))
```

И зачем вы ввод превращаете в целое число?

В какое целое число должно превратиться `+` или `*`?

А что за сравнение такое:

```
elif(c == -):
```

что вы с чем сравниваете? что должно храниться в переменной `с`?

Кстати скобки в питоне не нужны (необязательны) на таких сравнениях

Чтобы спрашивать `почему код не работает` желательно самому вначале ответить ПО КАЖДОЙ СТРОЧКЕ своей программы - что именно делает эта строчка и зачем

Answer (score 4):

Иван, консоль подсказывает, что пошло не так. Рекомендую вчитываться в выводимые ошибки и внимательно ознакомиться с типами данных в питоне.

Далее комментарии к коду и "рабочая" версия кода:

1. В начале программы задается три переменных через ввод от пользователя: `a`, `b` и `c`. Команда `input()` возвращает данные от пользователя в формате строки (`string`). Так как `a` и `b` для расчёта нужны целые числа (`int`), рекомендую `input()` сразу преобразовывать в целое число таким образом: `int(input(<код>))` или `float(input(<код>))` (если на входе хотим получать числа с плавающей точкой (`float`), например, 5.7 или 6.6). `с` же нужно оставить строкой - будет полезно потом для сравнения.
2. В блоке `if-elif` для таких простых условий не нужны скобки. Символ проверки равенства `==` используется корректно, но для операции нужно сравнивать значение со строковым типом (`str`), так как переменная `c` является строкой, т.е. обернуть символ в кавычки (например `'+'` или `"+"`) - это показываем питону, что это тип данных строка.
3. Для расчета переменной `d` мы при вводе данных от пользователя преобразовали строковый тип данных в целочисленный, поэтому оставим во всех блоках `if-elif` просто переменные a и b без преобразования типов данных.
4. Для вывода в консоль (`print()`) можно переменную `d` оставить в числовом формате, без преобразования типа данных. Оно тут ни к чему.

```py
a = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
b = int(input('Введите второе число: '))
c = input('Введите операцию (+ - * или /): ')

if c == '+':
    d = a + b
elif c == '-':
    d = a - b
elif c == '*':
    d = a * b
elif c == '/':
    d = a / b

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот ваш код, исправил его на более лучше:

```py
#coding: cp1251


d = 0
a = int(input('Введите первое число: ')) 
b = int(input('Введите второе число: '))
c = int(input('Введите (1 это +; 2 это - 3; это *; или 4 это /): '))

if c == 1:
    d += a + b
elif c == 2:
    d += a - b
elif c == 3:
    d += a * b
elif c == 4:
    d += a / b

print(d)
```